# Can't connect user without the home directory to Mac OS Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, sharing, user-account, server.app

When I try to connect user WITHOUT home directory - services only

[image: User with services only]

to the Mac OS X Server 3.1.2 on Mavericks I get the error:

```
Oct 30 12:55:17 Cassandra515i.local rpcsvchost[10115]: passwd entry for uid=502 homedirectory invalid
```

On the client side in the console log you get:

```
10/30/14 12:58:54.714 sharingd[423]: 12:58:54.714 : SDSharePointBrowser::handleEnumerateCallBack returned -6600
```

When creating the home directory for the user there is no problem.

Could you help me with that, what is the problem ?

Here are advanced option of that user:

Advanced option of the user:

[image: Advanced option of the user]

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you set a user to services only this limits them to no login.  As you can see in your Advanced Options the login shell is set to **/usr/bin/false**.  This will deny login.  If you want to share a folder with them setup File Sharing in the Server.app and give them permission to the file share.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to connect user WITHOUT home directory - services only

What were you expecting? You chose to set up a user for services only and then tried to login as that user. Of course it's going to fail.

Services-only is for users that need calendar, email, time machine etc. but not login. If you want to do a basic login that user needs a home folder.

Comment: Well, but I want to just share folders with them.